# Property injection in Ninject is not working

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have such a class

```
public sealed class SimpleTextIndex<T> : TextIndex where T : ITextParser
{
    [Inject]
    public T TextParser { get; set; }
    // something...
```

And dependency resolving method

```
public void Resolve() 
{
    Kernel = new StandardKernel();
    Kernel.Bind(typeof(ITextParser)).To(typeof(WordTextParser));
    Kernel.Bind(typeof(SimpleTextIndex<>)).ToSelf();
}
```

WordTextParser is a class, which implements ITextParser interface.
But, after calling Resolve() method and kernel's Get() method:

```
var textIndex = kernel.Get<SimpleTextIndex<ITextParser>>();
```

I'm getting a NullReferenceException (TextParser property in SimpleTextIndex is null)! 
But, if I write a default constructor for SimpleTextIndex this way:

```
public SimpleTextIndex()
{
  DependencyResolver.Kernel.Inject(this);
}
```

Everything works fine! Why?

Comment: I could not reproduce your issue. What is the version of Ninject that you are using? Does `SimpleTextIndex` have a constructor? Can you provide Complete code so that we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: Ninject 2.6.4. 
Yeah, SimpleTextIndex have a constructor without parameters.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to say. NullReferenceException I'm getting when trying to use TextParser property in SimpleTextIndex. If not to use it, there will be no exception :)

Comment: Complete code of SimpleTextIndex class: http://pastebin.com/bGcQUcQn

Comment: How did you obtain this version? Via Nuget? I cannot find it [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject/). Did you check to see if the value of `TextParser ` is null?

Comment: And here dependency configurator class: http://pastebin.com/z3hTaUUJ

Comment: Oh, sorry: version of Ninject is 3.2.2

Comment: Can you check to see if `TextParser` is null?

Comment: Yeah, I checked: TextParser is null.

Comment: Using of SimpleTextIndex: http://pastebin.com/TmCvng4a

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that property injection is done only after the object is constructed via the constructor, i.e., Ninject cannot set the property value before the constructor is done.

Since you are using the dependency from a method invoked from the constructor, then the property is not yet set and therefore its value is null.

Either don't use the dependency during construction or use Constructor Injection like this:

```
//[Inject] //remove this attribute
public T TextParser { get; set; }

public SimpleTextIndex(T parser, string text = "")
{
    TextParser = parser;
    ...
}
```

Comment: I think I am having this same problem. I think my problem is that I am mixing constructor injection with property injection.